# Unusual crash only on some device - async calls kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I am writing an Android App in Kotlin and I get this crash only on some HUAWEI tablet running Android API 17. However, I have tested it on a Sony Xperia and a Samsung galaxy s3 mini (or something like that), both running Android API 19 and there is no problem. The crash happens just before `val data = connection.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()` in the following code:

```
doAsync {
        val url = urlString
        val connection = URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        val responseCode = connection.responseCode
        uiThread {
            if (responseCode == 200) {
              // ENTERS IF AND CRASHES WITHOUT EXECUTING THE NEXT LINE
                val data = connection.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
                val response = connection.headerFields
                val parser = Parser()
                val stringBuilder = StringBuilder(data)
                val json = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject
            }
        }
    }
```

**App build.gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "appName"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

The message in Logs is `W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410a3930)` without anything else before or after.

It's the first app I develop for Android, so could someone help me understand what is going on and how can I fix this crash? Is it the API 17 to blame (but there is no warning of API specific functions in app), kotlins coroutines, HUAWEI device?

**Error Stack Trace** as requested in comments

```
  W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
   W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1120)
   W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
   W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
   W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
   W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
   W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
   W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:304)
   W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream.read(FixedLengthInputStream.java:45)
   W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244)
   W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:310)
   W/System.err:     at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:145)
   W/System.err:     at kotlin.io.TextStreamsKt.copyTo(ReadWrite.kt:117)
   W/System.err:     at kotlin.io.TextStreamsKt.copyTo$default(ReadWrite.kt:114)
   W/System.err:     at kotlin.io.TextStreamsKt.readText(ReadWrite.kt:101)
   W/System.err:     at deeplake.co.uk.livedemokotlin.login$attemptLogin$1$1.invoke(login.kt:85)
   W/System.err:     at deeplake.co.uk.livedemokotlin.login$attemptLogin$1$1.invoke(login.kt:26)
   W/System.err:     at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$uiThread$1.run(Async.kt:70)
   W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5119)
   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
   W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
   W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: maybe you should move `connection.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()` outside of `uiThread`?

Comment: uiThread forces the async tasks to perform in a linear order, delaying next process until the previous one executes.

Comment: @AlexIoja-Yang Please provide a stack trace or logged error. `connection.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()` this effectively uses network io on ui thread. Also the string allocated by `readText` might cause `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: @miensol I'm sorry but I'm not 100% sure if I'm doing it right. I put `data =` inside a `try{}` and then `catch(e: Exception){e.printStackTrace() ; Log.i("test', "test"}`. If that's correct, it doesn't actually show anything in the logs, this way it just performs the whole method whilst showing crash error on device and restarting once that's acknowledged.

Comment: @miensol I have checked and the length of text it's actually only 294 (on working devices), which is a lot less then the initial download where I get a string of about 600k (activity prior to this one)

Comment: @AlexIoja-Yang Just to clarify, you've wrapped entire block under `if` in `try` and still no error logged?

Comment: @miensol sorry, now I wrapped the whole if and updated my question with the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you reenter the UI thread too soon as you are still doing networking operations in this call: **connection.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()**

Have you tried doing this:

```
doAsync {
    val url = urlString
    val connection = URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    val responseCode = connection.responseCode

    if (responseCode == 200) {
        val data = connection.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
        val response = connection.headerFields
        val parser = Parser()
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder(data)
        uiThread {
            val json = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That worked thank you. Could you please just clarify for me, isn't data = connection.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText() an async task since it might take some time to receive all the information? By putting uiThread after it, I thought I'd access data before completion. Or is uiThread forcing it to finish all background tasks before starting. I will accept your answer regardless, but would really appreciate if you could clarify for me how is this working and not breaking it :).

Comment: Thank you too. This works because everything inside the doAsync{} block is already running asynchronously in relation to the rest of the app. Therefore you can perform lengthy network operations inside this block without any performance impact on the user experience. That is, up until the uiThread{} statement. You can read more about it here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/05/advanced-features-of-anko/